# Wait until Refrotfit return success or failure

Tags: android, retrofit

I have login button that when user click on it , I call Api-Service ( I use retrofit ) to check is he/she signed up or not , something like this

```
    private void loginUserService() {
    ServiceHelper.getInstance().loginUser(usernameEdtTxt.getText().toString(), passwordEdtTxt.getText().toString(), new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                isLoginSuccessfull = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            isLoginSuccessfull = false;
        }
    });

}
```

How can i wait until this process finished and return proper value ? ( while this call is async )

My last try : I put this method in AsynTask and get return value from OnPostExecute but it's seems not works fine !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and perhaps best way to achieve this is by using Events. Here is how you could try it with a library called [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

1. Using gradle, add the following line to your dependencies section:

   `compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'`
2. Now, register EventBus inside the activity's **onCreate** method or fragment where you want to be notified when the Retrofit request is either successful or failed. You register EventBus using a line like this:

   `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);`
3. Create a simple POJO (Plain Old Java Object) you could call it **RetrofitEvent** and add one variable like :

   `public boolean isRetrofitCompleted;`

   Then in your constructor of this class, initialize this variable. You can add a setter method if you want but that is not necessary.
4. Now, inside your Retrofit onSuccess() method, you can notify the activity or fragment that the event has been completed successfully by using the following line:

   `EventBus.getDefault().post(new RetrofitEvent(true));`

   Or if it fails:

   `EventBus.getDefault().post(new RetrofitEvent(false));`
5. Now go back to your activity class or fragment and listen for this event by overriding **onEvent** method like this:

   ```
   public void onEvent(RetrofitEvent event) {

      if(event.isRetrofitCompleted){

         //if you had  a progress dialog showing, hide it here.
         //then of course do what you needed here.
      }else{
         //the request might have failed here due to network issues
         //update the ui accordingly.
      }
   }
   ```

   6. Finally, remember to unregister EventBus in your onDestroy method like this:

   `EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);`

Comment: really usefull and well explained :)

Comment: It's throws Exception  "its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation" Do you know whats the reason ?

Comment: You don't need to use that annotation. Just override onEvent(EventName event)